# List most prevalent values with their corresponding sum

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, csv, awk

I want to get top N most prevalent values of a field in a CSV file
with their sum in another field. How may I do that with awk?

Suppose my file is:

```
v1,45
v3,20
v2,500
v3,100
v2,200
v1,55
v3,50
v1,10
```

and I need N=2 most occurring field 1 values with their sum of corresponding field2 values
in this case output would be:

```
v1,110
v3,170
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$2;c[$1]++}END{for(k in c)print c[k], k","a[k]}' file|sort -nr|awk 'NR<3&&$0=$2'
```

it could be solved in one awk, but this is more straightforward. :)

if you want to change your `N`, just modify the last awk cmd `NR<3...`

Comment: could you please interpret this in more details?

Comment: @user3144923 first awk, will do sum on same `vx`, and generate an output like `3 v1,110` the 3 is the occurrence count, 2nd part (separated by a space) is what we want, pass this to `sort -nr` decending sort by number. the result goes to awk again, we take only first two entries, and remove the first column, which was the `3`.

Comment: how could you scale second field values in output? for example I need to multiply all column values by a value computed in bash and outside awk, like $scale

Comment: pass the value to 1st awk, using awk's `printf` to scale @user3144923

Comment: how does this $0=$2 work? I tested several combinations but I couldn't understand the relationship from results/// As another little question, how could I pass tail -n +2 of a file as Input file in your script?

Comment: @user3144923 as I said in another comment, we have text format `3 xx,xxx`, so two cols `3` and `xx,xxx` `$0=$2` simply removes the 1st column. about the tail, `tail ... file|awk ...` and of course, you need remove the input file part of awk command.

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu awk there is an `asort` function, so you could do

```
gawk -f a.awk file
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    a[$1]++
    b[$1]+=$2
}

END {
    for (i in a)
        a[i]=a[i]"\t"i
    n=asort(a)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        split(a[i],c,"\t")
        ind[i]=c[2]
    }
    for (i=n; i>n-2; i--) 
        print ind[i],b[ind[i]]
}
```

Output:

```
v3,170
v1,110
```